# jQuery mousewheel fire only once while animation not finished

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bind, mousewheel, unbind

I have two functions `animation1()` and `animation2()`. Each of these functions contains a few animations (`animate()`) in a chain. Each animation set has two parts:

1. move object in scene1 > hide them > show object on scene 2.
2. The second animation set is in reverse - hide object on scene2 > show object on scene1 and move them to right

Animations are working.

What I need is to bind these animations to `mousewheel` with these rules:

- when I scroll down > run animation1
- when I scroll up > run animation2
- do not run animation2 while animation1 has not finished (and vice versa)
- (TODO) do not run naimation1 multiple times because of mousewheel (the same for anim.2)

This is my code, which is working but runs multiple times and creates a big mess because of `mousewheel` deltas fired multiple times. I tried many solutions found on SO without any luck. I also tried unbinding `mousewheel`, which is working; but I don't know how to rebind it back and scroll up.

```
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll mousewheel onmousewheel', function(e){
    //$(this).unbind('DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll mousewheel onmousewheel');
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
      if ($('.scene1 .image').is(':visible') && $('#content').find(":animated").length === 0) {
        animation1();
      }
    }
    else {
      if ($('.scene2 .image').is(':visible') && $('#content').find(":animated").length === 0) {
        animation2();
      }
    }
});
```

Thanks for any advice!

**UPDATE**
At this time, this is my best solution.. animation is fired only once (using jquery.mousewheel, but can be used also without this lib)
http://jsfiddle.net/wkupb1Ln/6/

```
$('#content').mousewheel(function(event) {
    if ($('.image').is(':animated') ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( (event.deltaY < 0) && $('.scene2 .image').hasClass('invisible') ) {
        animation1();
    }
    if ( (event.deltaY > 0) && $('.scene1 .image').hasClass('invisible') ) {
        animation2();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the scrollstop/scrollstart plugin found here: https://github.com/ssorallen/jquery-scrollstop

Then I would refactor the code to something like the following, where you measure the "delta" by calculating the scrolling after a certain time interval (250ms here)

```
$(window).on("scrollstart", function() {
  var Position1 = $window.scrollTop();
  setTimeout(function () {
    var Position2 = $window.scrollTop(), delta = Position2 - Position1;
    if (delta < 0 && $('.scene1 .image').is(':visible') && $('#content').find(":animated").length === 0) {
      animation1();
    } else {
      if (delta > 0 && $('.scene2 .image').is(':visible') && $('#content').find(":animated").length === 0) {
        animation2();
      }
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

Binding to "scrollstart" should ensure the appropriate function only fires once.

Comment: Thanks, but timeout isn't solution for me. I tried your code and the second animation was running multiple times.